# Make regex match only the capturing group

Tags: regex, split, pyspark

Due to the technology I'm currently working with (PySpark API), I need to adjust a regex so that the full match corresponds to the capturing group.

I want to use it as a delimiter pattern in a [**split** function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split)

This function splits an input string according to the matched substring, not the capturing group.
Hence why I need to match the \s+ caracters (that I currently only capture).

Here is a [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/j1QgnS/1) or here: `(\s)+(?:\d*\s*)(?=RUE|BOULEVARD|AVENUE)`

I tried to extend the positive lookahead to combine the possibility that a \d+\s+ may be present before and therefore match a different \s. Didnt work so far.

The split function's output I wish to obtain is the following:

```
[7 BOULEVARD LAPIN BLANC,AVENUE MR LIEVRE,18 RUE PIERRE LAPIN]
```

Comment: Didn't understand the output. Is that the output of `split` function

Comment: Indeed it is, I'll update my post. I basically wanna match only the \s+ that are currently captured in my example.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/j1QgnS/2) what you want?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Elegant and straightforward, I didnt think about using the negative lookbehind and the `?` quantifier. Well done, feel free to post this as an answer so I can resolve this topic. Thanks for the lightning fast answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know pyspark but I guess it supports these things, split on spaces that are not preceded by a digit but followed by an optional digit then the type of street.

```
(?<!\d)\s+(?=(?:\d+\s)?(?:RUE|BOULEVARD|AVENUE))
```

In the demo I use a substitution with `\n` that simulate the split.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/j1QgnS/2)

Comment: Well spotted @bobblebubble, I don't seem to find one, \d*\s* seems slighly faster.